# Vert.x undeploy verticle throws IllegalStateException Unknown deployment

Tags: java, vert.x

Looking through the logs of a Vert.x application, I noticed the following exception when undeploying verticles (it's the same exception for all 3):

```
Failed to undeploy netsci.graphservice.verticles.CommandVerticle
Failed to undeploy netsci.graphservice.verticles.QueryVerticle
Failed to undeploy netsci.graphservice.verticles.EventVerticle
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown deployment
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.undeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:203)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.undeploy(VertxImpl.java:616)
    at microservice.MasterMicroserviceVerticle.undeploySupportingVerticle(MasterMicroserviceVerticle.java:462)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1548)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at microservice.MasterMicroserviceVerticle.stopSupportingVerticles(MasterMicroserviceVerticle.java:433)
    at microservice.MasterMicroserviceVerticle.lambda$stop$14(MasterMicroserviceVerticle.java:383)
    at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$compose$1(Future.java:270)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:126)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:88)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:152)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:81)
    at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$compose$1(Future.java:275)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:126)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:88)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:152)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.handle(FutureImpl.java:23)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:126)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:133)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.complete(FutureImpl.java:95)
    at microservice.MasterMicroserviceVerticle.lambda$null$11(MasterMicroserviceVerticle.java:363)
    at microservice.messaging.impl.BufferKafkaProducerService.lambda$shutdown$2(BufferKafkaProducerService.java:97)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:81)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:287)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:445)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, they are all deployed and have a deployment ID:

```
Deployed: 213f1978-a595-4af1-8129-29de872e9907
Deployed: e46839f1-2dd2-4cce-9e12-66e09677b97a
Deployed: 8fdfd492-e005-4503-875e-13d73c633b2c
```

The deployment ID's are stored in a synchronized map, with the verticle class as the key and the the deployment id as the value. When queried, it shows that they are correctly stored:

```
class netsci.graphservice.verticles.QueryVerticle: e46839f1-2dd2-4cce-9e12-66e09677b97a
class netsci.graphservice.verticles.CommandVerticle: 8fdfd492-e005-4503-875e-13d73c633b2c
class netsci.graphservice.verticles.EventVerticle: 213f1978-a595-4af1-8129-29de872e9907
```

Prior to the call to endeploy, if I check which verticle is being undeployed, I get can see that the valid deployment ID is being passed into the call to undeploy:

```
Undeploying: e46839f1-2dd2-4cce-9e12-66e09677b97a
Undeploying: 8fdfd492-e005-4503-875e-13d73c633b2c
Undeploying: 213f1978-a595-4af1-8129-29de872e9907
```

Here are the relevant bits of code:

```
public abstract class MasterMicroserviceVerticle extends MicroserviceVerticle {

  private final Map<Class, String> supportingVerticles =
      Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Class, String>());

  ...

  private Future<Void> deploySupportingVerticle(Class verticle) {

    Future<Void> future = Future.future();

    vertx.deployVerticle(
        verticle.getName(),
        new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config()),
        asyncResult -> {
          if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            // Assign deployment ID to verticle map.
            String depId = asyncResult.result();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(depId);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            supportingVerticles.put(verticle, depId);
            healthStatusService.setHealth(verticle.getName(), HealthStatus.PASSING);
            logger.info("Deployed {}", verticle.getName());
            future.complete();
          } else {
            healthStatusService.setHealth(verticle.getName(), HealthStatus.FAILING);
            logger.error("Failed to deploy {}", verticle.getName(), asyncResult.cause());
            future.fail(asyncResult.cause());
          }
        });

    return future;
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void stop(Future<Void> stopFuture) throws Exception {

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    for (Class c : supportingVerticles.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(c + ": " + supportingVerticles.get(c));
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    ...
      return mongoFuture;
    }).compose(handler -> {
      Future<Void> verticlesFuture = Future.future();

      stopSupportingVerticles(verticlesFuture.completer());

      return verticlesFuture;
    }).compose(handler ->
      logger.info("Undeployed service");
      stopFuture.completer();
    }, stopFuture);
  }

  protected void stopSupportingVerticles(Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {

    List<Future> undeployable = supportingVerticles
        .keySet()
        .stream()
        .map(this::undeploySupportingVerticle)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CompositeFuture.all(undeployable)
        .setHandler(asyncResult -> {
          if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
          } else {
            handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(asyncResult.cause()));
          }
        });
  }

  private Future<Void> undeploySupportingVerticle(Class verticle) {

    Future<Void> future = Future.future();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Undeploying: " + supportingVerticles.get(verticle));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    vertx.undeploy(supportingVerticles.get(verticle), asyncResult -> {
      healthStatusService.setHealth(verticle.getName(), HealthStatus.FAILING);
      if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        logger.info("Undeployed {}", verticle.getName());
        future.complete();
      } else {
        logger.error("Failed to undeploy {}", verticle.getName(), asyncResult.cause());
        future.fail(asyncResult.cause());
      }
    });

    return future;
  }
}
```

Please excuse all the `System.out.println()`'s, I've thrown them in there to help me get a better idea of what's going on and should probably record this info in the logs. But for now, I'd just appreciate any help understanding why Vert.x is saying the deployments are unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vert.x specs](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#_asynchronous_verticle_start_and_stop):

> You don’t need to manually undeploy child verticles started by a verticle, in the verticle’s stop method. Vert.x will automatically undeploy any child verticles when the parent is undeployed.

You can verify this by overriding the `stop()` method in the child verticles. I would say, that at the time when `MasterMicroserviceVerticle` is being undeployed, the other ones are already undeployed.

Comment: If I want to control the stop sequence to make sure any remaining work in the additional verticles is complete before they shut down, which is why I'm overriding `stop()` and calling undeploy. I don't make any calls to `super.stop()`, so how do I prevent Vert.x from undeploying them automatically?

Comment: I am not sure if you can control the undeployment sequence. If you have a look at `io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.DeploymentImpl#doUndeploy` you can see that all child verticles are automatically undeployed before their parent.
Maybe you can check in your child verticles if there is some work left to do, and complete the `stopFuture` only after the remaining work is finished.

Comment: I'm not completing the stop future until the work is complete. I had thought that by calling `undeploy()` would initiate the stopping. Now I have a better understanding of why it's behaving in this way I can go and rethink my strategy for shutting down neatly. Thanks.

Comment: @amb85 Can you please share your new clean strategy to prevent child verticles from being undeployed?